Hausdorff dimension: The dimension of boundary of a set
I can't understand the following statement.

If (perhaps not closed) set $S$  has dimension $n$, then the boundary could have any dimension from $0$ to $n$. (Could someone give me an example?)
If S  is closed and has dimension $n$, then the boundary is either empty or has dimension $\ge n−1$.


1. Example
Let $C$ be a self-similar Cantor set in $\mathbb R$.  It is closed, bounded, nowhere dense.  It can be chosen with any Hausdorff dimension $0 < s < 1$.  Let $S$ be the complement of $C$.  Then the open set $S$ has dimension $1$ and the boundary of $S$ is $C$.
